# "Cooperative gesture handling" in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

Is there any implementation in OL resembling Google Maps' "Cooperative gesture handling" to prevent unwanted panning/zooming of the map?

(Google maps uses ctrl+scroll for mouse, two-finger-swipe for panning)